# Symfony 6.4 - How to use the prod environnement with custom APP_ENV

Tags: php, configuration, symfony6

At my current company, when a project moves to the qualification phase before going into production, the environment variable `APP_ENV` is set to `qual` (which I can't change).

However, the error pages I've created don't appear; instead, the same error page as in the development environment is shown. In `APP_ENV=qual`, it needs to function exactly like `APP_ENV=prod`. How can I achieve this? I know I can use a controller, but after the qualification phase, `APP_ENV` will be set to `prod`.

My error pages are located in `Templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception`.

In the `config/packages` directory, I added a directory named 'qual' with all the necessary `.yaml` files and replaced `when@prod` with `when@qual`, but it didn't work. I tried following the official documentation, but I don't clearly understand what it's saying.

I want to create a new environment that works exactly like `prod`, or when the environment is set to 'qual', I want it to be changed to 'prod'.

Comment: I think that you need to specify in your question that you are using Symphony in order to get more attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `APP_DEBUG` variable to false manually, as the Dotenv component automatically sets it to true when the `APP_ENV` variable is set to anything else other than "prod".

Comment: It works, not exactly the way I wanted, but it's enough for me for now. Thankss you ^^
In '.env' i put 'APP_DEBUG=0'